# How to speed up running docker-container with node.js?

Tags: node.js, deployment, docker, dockerfile

I develop application with node.js and docker. My deploy process includes few steps:

1. build docker-image
2. run docker-container

I have 19 seconds to running of my node_js container. But i want to reduce the time to 1-5 seconds at least. 
Most of run container time it takes `npm install`.

It is possible to speed up running my node.js application?

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Vovan

# docker build --build-arg NODE_VERSION=any_version .
ARG NODE_VERSION=4.4.2

ARG EXTERNAL_GIT_URI=local_gitlab
ARG EXTERNAL_GIT_PORT=22

# variables
ENV TERM=xterm

# use bash instead of sh
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# essential system updates and soft
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -yq \
        ntp \
        build-essential \
        curl \
        mc \
        nano \
        git \
    && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash \
    # add nvm as term command
    && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    #
    && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} \
    && nvm alias default ${NODE_VERSION} 

# home directory 
RUN useradd -m -d /home/app -s /bin/bash app -u9999

# copy keys in image
ADD for_gitlab /root/.ssh/for_gitlab
ADD config /root/.ssh/config
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/* \
    && ssh-keyscan -p ${EXTERNAL_GIT_PORT} ${EXTERNAL_GIT_URI} > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# copy script and make it executable
WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir config
ADD starter.sh /config
CMD ["/config/starter.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /config/starter.sh

WORKDIR /home/app
```

### starter.sh

```
APP_DIR=/home/app/${GIT_REPO_NAME}
GIT_CLONE_URI=git@local_gitlab:${GIT_GROUP}/${GIT_REPO_NAME}.git

cd /home/app
git clone ${GIT_CLONE_URI} --depth 1 --branch ${GIT_REPO_BRANCH}

# permissions
find ${APP_DIR} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find ${APP_DIR} -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chown -R app:app ${APP_DIR}
#

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use default
cd ${APP_DIR} && npm install 
find ${APP_DIR}/node_modules -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find ${APP_DIR}/node_modules -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
node ${SCRIPT}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditinally run `npm install` by checking if `package.json` has been modified since the last the installation. Here I'm checking if `package.json` modified time is newer than `node_modules` modified time :

```
[ package.json -nt node_modules ] && npm install ;
```

Comment: In this case, the container will not stateless, right? If I run container first time `npm install` anyway will processing long time.

Comment: Yup, for the first time, you can't avoid `npm install` with your current approach. To avoid `npm install` during container run, you have to do the cloning and installation at the image building step.